# Why is there one `Atomic*` type for many primitive type instead of a generic `Atomic<T>`?

Tags: rust, atomic

Looking at [the `std::sync::atomic` module](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/atomic/index.html), one can see a bunch of different `Atomic*` types, like `AtomicU32`, `AtomicI16` and more. Why is that?

Rust has generics and – as I see it – it would be possible to add a generic `Atomic<T>` where `T` is bounded by some trait defined in the module (in Java-ish naming: `Atomicable`). That trait would be implemented by the types that could be handled in an atomic fashion and users could just use `Atomic<u32>` instead of `AtomicU32`.

**Why isn't there a generic `Atomic<T>`? Why have a bunch of different types instead?**

Comment: `AtomicBool` doesn't have the same functions than `AtomicU32`. Do you think about some `AtomicInteger<T>` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The purpose of having an `AtomicU8` (for example) is using the underlying hardware to perform [atomic instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap), e.g. on x86 the [`CMPXCHG` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpxchg).

The original [RFC #1505](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1505) suggested a `Atomic<T>` type. [One of the main concern was](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1505#issuecomment-187441331), that people would use `T` in an unintended way, e.g. using `Atomic<[u8; 32]>` which would not be possible to support, because of the lack of hardware that support those.
A fallback/workaround by using a `Mutex` was proposed, but it felt like cheating, because the compiler would behave differently for different `T`s.

[It was finally closed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1505#issuecomment-210207997) in favor of [RFC #1543](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1543) which introduced the Atomic{I,U}{8,16,32,64} types we know today.

It was then implemented in [PR #33048](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/33048) and stabilized in [PR #56753](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/56753) which is Rust 1.34.0.

To ensure, that the underlying hardware really supports the atomic operations the types are having a cfg attribute, e.g. for `AtomicI8` it is [`#[cfg(target_has_atomic = "8")]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/sync/atomic.rs.html#1892), for `AtomicI16` it is [`#[cfg(target_has_atomic = "16")]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/sync/atomic.rs.html#1924) etcetera.

Comment: It may be interesting to note the difference with C++ as it actually went with the `std::atomic<T>` way. It therefore presents a unified interface, however there is actually no guarantee that `std::atomic<T>` is always implemented with actual atomic instructions. Depending on the platform, it may use either an atomic instruction or require some fancier trickery like a mutex: this is exposed by an `always_lockfree` associated constant.

Comment: But that's possible because C++ does support specialization, whereas Rust doesn't.

Comment: Yes and no, but that's besides the point I was trying to make. C++11 introduced `std::atomic<T>`, 5 years before the `Atomic` RFC. I expect that the experience of working with `std::atomic<T>`, and the footgun of the generated code using atomic instructions on some platforms but not others, partly informed the feedback on the "fallback" of the `Atomic` RFC.

Comment: @MatthieuM: I don't get it. There's nothing preventing Rust from having `Atomic<T>` only valid for `T` types that are guaranteed to be atomic, with compile-time checks for users. The current atomic interface provided by Rust seems unnecessarily non-generic.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo can you provide a small example on how to enforce, that `T` is one of the forms? Also, how you do generate the needed assembly then?

Comment: [Here's one way you could do it on top of the existing types](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8e9ccb32b2f7f8df3b9d538ec561cb79). It could presumably be cleaner if the atomic types had originally been designed with this in mind; I don't know why they weren't, but it also doesn't bother me too much.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: Indeed. What hellow points out, though, is that you cannot have an `Atomic<T>` that is sometimes really atomic and sometimes not, depending on the type, without using specialization.

Comment: also atomic is not here to be used a lot, it has very specific use case, if you start to want generic atomic because you need a lot of them, you have a bigger design problem.

Comment: I had something like the code by trentcl in mind: a trait that ensures that `T` can be used atomically on the current platform (i.e. the `cfg` attributes on the `impl` blocks). Then one could use `Atomic<T>`. I agree that the C++ solution ala "atomic if it's supported, otherwise fallback" is bad. But I think one could do better in Rust.

Comment: There is the [`atomic` crate](https://crates.io/crates/atomic) which offers `Atomic<T> where T: Copy` and does it like C++: real atomic if supported, otherwise lock-based fallback.

Comment: FYI: I just release [the crate `atomig`](https://github.com/LukasKalbertodt/atomig) which offers a generic wrapper `Atomic<T>` for types that can actually be used in atomic fashion on the target platform.